# CDI injection with ExceptionMapper- @inject null

Tags: java, cdi, code-injection, inject, provider

I have the following ExceptionMapper:

```
 @Provider
 public class GenericExceptionMapper 
 implements ExceptionMapper<Exception> {
 @Inject
 private ExceptionDAO exceptionDAO;

@Override
public Response toResponse(Exception e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    return Response.status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
            .type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
            .entity(e.getMessage())
            .build();
}
```

The exceptionDAO is always null. I have a beans.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee /beans_1_0.xsd"
></beans>
```

I have tried injecting alot of classes, but they always show as null.

Comment: Do you have CDI working anywhere in your project? What sort of project (EAR, WAR, etc) is this? Where is the beans.xml specifically? How is `ExceptionDAO` annotated?

Comment: Oh, some more questions: Does `GenericExceptionMapper` have any annotations? How do you get one?

Comment: Its a JAR project. Yes CDI is working in other porojects

Comment: Inside META-INF in src/main/resources

Comment: You've only answered half my questions, so let me make this plain: CDI injection will only work in a CDI-aware bean. For example, if this were a REST resource, you'd annotate it `@RequestScoped` and then the injection would work. I would suggest you annotate your `GenericExceptionMapper` with `@RequestScoped` and see if that works.

Comment: I tried it but it is still null.

Comment: ExceptionDAO doesnt have any annotations.

Comment: Ok, that's a big problem right there. `ExceptionDAO` needs to be either a scoped bean or be provided by a method with a `@Produces` annotation.

Comment: This Exception Class has a @Provider. It is meant to handle exception for rest services. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Both the class being managed (`ExceptionDAO`) and the class injecting it need to be CDI-aware. In this case, this will probably involve marking *both* classes with `@RequestScoped` (or other CDI normal scope).

Do not get rid of the `@Provider` or other JAX-RS annotations; just add the CDI annotation.